# Strange behavior with setting multiple values simultaneously

Tags: variable-definitions, assignment

I'm having some strange behavior when trying to set multiple variables using {x,y,z} = {1,2,3}.

When I enter "{a,b,c,a',b',c'} = {1,2,3,4,5,6}", it sets a,b,c,a',b',c' to 1,2,3,4,5,6 as desired.

However, when I enter "{a,b,c,a',b',c'} = {2,0,0,0,0,2}", it sets a,b,c,a',b',c' to 2,0,0,0,2,2

Why is this happening?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWL3h.jpg

I'm also confused about the warning messages appearing when I enter "Clear[a,b,c,a',b',c']". I have previously defined a',b',c' to be various integers. Why is it complaining when I try to clear them?

Comment: `Clear[a, b, c, a1, b1, c1];
{a, b, c, a1, b1, c1} = {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2};
b1`.

Comment: '  is refer to `Derivative`

Comment: In *Mathematica*, symbol names cannot include `'`'s and underscores and other non-letter/number symbols.